# How to access a file via htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a folder structure like

```
Controller
  |_check.php

View
  |_  .htaccess
  |_ index.php
  |_  Webroot
          |_ js
              |_common.js
.htaccess
```

In .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ View/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) View/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

In View/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

The outer .htaccess file links to  View folder  and there `View/.htaccess` links to index.php.

There is button in `index.php`(view file) with ajax to `check.php`.

I have given common.js The corresponding ajax function url as

```
var url = 'check.php'; // OR '../Controller/check.php'
```

The problem is the ajax is not working properly with two urls.

Whether I need change the folder structure to correct it or do I need to alter any htaccess file for accessing the `check.php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not about the folder structure but rather the htaccess rewrite rules that are wrong.

Your htaccess in the "root" redirects all requests to the View folder (which defaults to index.php, I assume)

I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish, if you explain I might be able to help you.

In your current setup, you can't access any file besides View/index.php (even when passing GET argument url)

EDIT:

In that case, if you wish to View/index.php be the only file accessible and force people to pass through View/index.php file, you can use PHP session variable.

Something like this...

in the top of your view.php file:

```
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['viewCheck'] = true;
   //rest of view.php code
```

in your check.php code (or the file you're trying to access via AJAX)

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['viewCheck']) && $_SESSION['viewCheck'] === true) {
    //Code of check.php
} else {
    //Error message or redirect to view.php, for instance

    //error message example
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');

    //Redirect example
    header("Location: http://www.yourhost.com/View/index.php");
}
```

NOTE 1:
You should remove the rewrite rules of your htaccess files.

NOTE 2:
Keep in mind that this is not bullet proof (and can be spoofed) since:

1. **If someone visits View/index.php then he can access check.php freely. This can be *mitigated* if the session is killed after the ajax request. You can accomplish that if the ajax request consists in 2 requests, for instance, one to get a session key which expires in 10 seconds for instance, and then use that key to obtain the results from check.php**
2. Session can be spoofed too (read more [here](https://github.com/sobstel/sesshin/wiki/PHP-Session-Security---Threats))

Comment: I have three files `index.php`(view page), `common.js`, and `result.php(php)` in root folder. On clicking a button in `index.php`(view) file will trigger an ajax function to `result.php`.
The problem is everyone can access the `result.php` directly. How to avoid it? I try make folder structure, that all php files(`check.php`) are in folder behind root. So it will not accessed directly from browser. I am not familar with rewrite rue.

Comment: Does the results have to be in ajax? Can't you use a regular form?

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just set the path for the domain on the "View" folder, so noone can access you controllers etc. ?

I think this should also be more simple than playing around with .htaccess !

This is the way most PHP Frameworks do it..

And if you need to access the functions of check.php you can make a "ajax.php" that checks if the request is ok, and then uses "check.php" to catch the result!

Comment: because AJAX scripts must be accessible from outside (hence my question if he can't change to a regular form)

Comment: you could make a "ajax.php" that checks if the request is ok, and then uses "check.php" to catch the result!

Comment: If request is valid, then I can use `require('../Controller/check.php');` in `View/ajax.php`. Like that?

Comment: yes, you can. But its the same using 1 file or 2 files. You can check for "validity" directly in check.php. Using ajax.php is just moving the validity check from one file to the other.